# Action Script 3 Errors 1061 and 1120

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

### I'm new to this, not sure what I'm doing wrong, Thank you for help

Please see my code below:

```
protected function getXMLUrl(vid:String):String {

    //return 'http://v.iask.com/v_play.php?vid='+ vid;

    var rand:*   = Math.random();
    var f1:*     = function (param1:Number) : Number {

        var _loc_2:* = param1.toString(2);
        var _loc_3:* = _loc_2.substring(0, _loc_2.length - 6);
        return parseInt(_loc_3, 2);
    };

    var Str1:*   = "Z6prk18aWxP278cVAH";
    var Date1:*  = new Date();
    var Num:*    = this.f1(int(Date1.time / 1000));
    var str:*    = vid.toString() + str1 + Num + rand.toString();
    var hash:*   = MD5.hash(str);
    var encode:* = hash.substr(0, 16).toString() + Num.toString();

    return 'http://v.iask.com/v_play.php?vid='+ vid + "&ran=" + rand + "&p=i&k=" + encode;
}
```

And here are the Errors I'm getting

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method f1 through a reference with static type

1120: Access of undefined property MD5.

1120: Access of undefined property str1.
```

Comment: Look for f1 in the whole code, perhaps it's defined somehwere. MD5 is probably from an as3 crypto library. str1 should be defined somewhere. The problem is you've decompiled a a video player and the decompiled is a mess (not types for most variables, non-informative variable names (_loc_2,_loc_3, etc.). I'm not 100% the decompiler managed to get everything, but it's mostly up to you to take function apart and try to test each piece in isolation, then try to put everything together and test.Hopefully the hints above will help, otherwise I doubt there will be people willing to face this headache

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed it

add

```
import com.adobe.crypto.MD5;
```

also deleted all the " :* "